# Which is more Pythonic to split a string into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

today I was checking different ways to split a string in python and I wondered which way is more pythonic, here are two codes of the thing I'm talking about:

```py
x = list("python")
print(x) # ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

or this:

```py
*x, = "python"
print(x) # ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both approaches achieve the same result but have different readability and may not be immediately clear to all Python developers.

1. **`list("python")`:** This is straightforward and self-explanatory. It aligns well with the Zen of Python's principles like "Readability counts" and "Explicit is better than implicit" ([PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).
2. **`*x, = "python"`:** This uses tuple unpacking and while it's a neat trick, it's less readable for those not familiar with the unpacking syntax in Python. This goes against the "Readability counts" principle.

Given these considerations, `list("python")` is generally more "Pythonic" according to established guidelines and principles from core Python developers like Guido van Rossum and Tim Peters.